# How to send the RFID card no read using Raspberry Pi to smart contract so the details can be stored on Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, oracles

Raspberry Pi reads an RFID card and has to send the RFID number to the smart contract to check further details related to the RFID number. Based on the details the payment is done and stored on the Ethereum blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

It is same as a get call that you make with a function written in the smart contract using api like web3.

You will have to write a function to return the details when RFID card number is passed as an argument to the function.

Comment: In which file do i write the function to return the details of the RFID?